# Recommended way to handle spring-boot application/external config?

Tags: java, spring, configuration, spring-boot

What's the recommended approach for handling application configuration in spring boot? For example, I have some things I want to load from files (in an override chain) like the database connection details. I have other things I want to load from my database itself (like runtime changeable app settings) and still others that I want to allow the user to change programmatically.

I am guessing what I really have here is 2 different use cases and I just need to treat them as separate and handle spring configuration one way and application configuration using something like http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/ but I wanted to make sure I am not missing some spring (or boot) way of doing things.

I would have normally asked this on the forums or mailing lists but I understand that we are supposed to use stackoverflow for this now so please let me know if there is a better venue for this type of question.

Comment: Sounds like the advice is to mostly do my own thing outside of spring... is that about right?

Answer (score 1):

I usually define 2 level of configuration:

- default value using `@Value("${configurationKey:defaultValue}")`;
- application personalized configuration using `@PropertySource("${configurationLocation:classpath:}/my-application.properties")`;

This way the application have the default values and will not throw any exception if configuration key is not found on `PropertyResolver`. Additionally `-DconfigurationLocation=file:///properties/files/` (for this case) could be defined a personalized path where the `my-application.properties` file could be loaded from and overwrite the default configuration values without a new deployment.

For the configuration stored in database, I would go for another approach like `commons-configuration` as you pointed.

Answer (score -1):

There are a bunch of options available to you, Spring Boot gives you some nice ones which give you that override chain you were looking for (using Profiles).  I wrote a [blog piece](http://hoserdude.com/2014/06/19/spring-boot-configurationproperties-and-profile-management-using-yaml/) about some of that.  If you want distributed configuration management you may want to explore [Spring Cloud](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/) which looks quite promising however I have yet to try it.